# ravendb NodeJS, load related document and create a nested result in a query

Tags: node.js, typescript, ravendb

I have an index that returns something like this

```
Company_All {
    name : string;
    id : string;
    agentDocumentId : string
}
```

is it possible to load the related agent document and then generate a nested result with selectFields and QueryData like this

```
ICompanyView  {
  companyName : 'Warner',
  user { 
    documentId : 'A/1'
    firstName : 'john',
    lastName : 'paul'
   }
}
```

I need something like the below query that obviously doesn't work as I expect:

```
    const queryData = new QueryData(
        ["name", "agentDocumentId", "agent.firstName", "agent.lastName"],
        ["companyName", "user.documentId", "user.lastName", "user.firstName"]);

    return await session.query<Company_AllResult>({ index: Company_All })
        .whereEquals("companyId", request.companyId)
        .include(`agents/${agentDocumentId}`) // ????
        .selectFields(queryData,ICompanyView)
        .single();
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that using:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.4/nodejs/indexes/indexing-related-documents

This is called indexing related documents, and is accessible at indexing time, not query time.

Alternatively, you have the `filter` clause, which has access to the `load`ed document, but I wouldn't generally recommend doing this.

Comment: See also **index-related documents demo** in: https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/nodejs/related-documents/index-related-documents

Comment: thank you guys, what about projection, can I generate a nested result in query, with QueryData or something like that?

Comment: When querying an index, the query results can be projected.
pls see **project index query results** demo  https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/nodejs/static-indexes/project-index-results

Answer (score 1):

Generally:

- When you query an index, the results of querying the index are the documents from the collection the index was defined on.
- Index-fields defined in the index are used to filter the index-query
  but the results are still documents from the original collection.
- If you define an index that indexes content from a **related-document** then when making an index-query you can **filter** the documents by the indexed-fields from the related documents, but the results are still documents from the original collection.
- When making an index-query (or any other query) you can project the query results so that Not the full documents of the original collection are returned but some other object.

Now:

- To project/get data from the indexed related-document you have **2 options:**

1. [Store](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/nodejs/static-indexes/store-fields-in-index) the index-fields from the related-document in the index.
   (Store all -or- specific fields).
   This way you have access to that content when making a projection in your query.

   See this [code sample.](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb-nodejs-client/blob/v5.2/test/Ported/Issues/RavenDB_16334.ts)
2. Don't store the index-fields from the related-document,

   then you will be able to use the index-fields to filter by in your query,

   but to get content you will need to use 'include' feature in your query,

   and then use the session.load, which will Not make another trip to the server.

   i.e. https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/nodejs/related-documents/query-related-documents